# How do you preprocess files in the Android assets folder with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a set of assets for an Android app that need to be pre-processed by a custom tool before being put into the final build.

Can I do this in gradle? How?

Comment: What kind of preprocessing ?

Comment: In this case, a shader transpiler.